# DBMS to store RSS feeds

Tags: rss, database

I'm not very experienced with DBMS systems so I need some advice about which DBMS to use for storing RSS feeds.

The DBMS must be available on Linux and be free. I have some experience with MySQL but I am unsure if it performs fast enough to handle the storage and updates of hundreds of thousands of xml documents.

Comment: Would you be storing the entire XML feeds in the database? Or just the data needed to create the feed?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to provide more informations, but almost all DBMS could do a good job at this.

SQL Server Express is free and easy to use though, so that should be a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the DBMS can be sufficent to store RSS feeds the questions should be:

- What DBMS do you have experience with?
- What DBMS can you afford?
- What DBMS has client libraries for your platform?